# Call By string in Python

Tags: python, class, call, function

I am learning Python. I want to call a function from a String.
I made a sample program for this.

```
class Calling:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.Callto(a)
    def Callto(self,a):
        re=self.Hello(a)    
        print "Calling= "+re    # Here L= CallMe
        self.re()               # Error is in this line 
    def Hello(self,a):
        b="Me"
        return a+b  
    def CallMe():
        print "I am Called"

x=Calling("Call")
```

> Traceback: AttributeError: Calling instance has no attribute 're'

*So far what I got is I cant call function with string. What can I do to make this string ('re') callable?*
***Thanks for reading***

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: I have another program which will take string value by opening txt file and call one by one... but that program is very big to share... So I made a sample problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can feed the function to a dict and call it from there.

```
>>> def foo():
        print 'foo'



>>> def bar():
        print 'bar'


>>> funcs = {
             'foo':foo,
             'bar':bar
            }
>>> funcs['foo']()
foo
>>> funcs['bar']()
bar
>>>
```

Comment: This is a good answer, But If I could write 'foo':foo dynamically then that would be great. In my program I shall get a string named foo from a txt file and I will have to call foo.. So for me there is no option to write funcs{ 'All my functions'} manually..

Comment: If your using a class/module you can use getattr function.